# Understanding purpose of returning self in context manager class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, with-statement, contextmanager

Trying to understanding how context managers work to catch errors, but more specifically the role of the `__enter__()` method in a class created to be used as a context manager, how it works in the 'error catching' process here, and why it is that `self` is all that's returned in the `__enter__()` method.

Given the following use of a context manager to catch an error:

```
import unittest
class InvoiceCalculatorTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_no_pay(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            pay = divide_pay(0, {"Alice": 3.0, "Bob": 3.0, "Carol": 6.0})
```

Here is what I believe is the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/case.py#L179) for `assertRaises`:

```
class _AssertRaisesContext(_AssertRaisesBaseContext):
    """A context manager used to implement TestCase.assertRaises* methods."""

    _base_type = BaseException
    _base_type_str = 'an exception type or tuple of exception types'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is None:
            try:
                exc_name = self.expected.__name__
            except AttributeError:
                exc_name = str(self.expected)
            if self.obj_name:
                self._raiseFailure("{} not raised by {}".format(exc_name,
                                                                self.obj_name))
            else:
                self._raiseFailure("{} not raised".format(exc_name))
        else:
            traceback.clear_frames(tb)
        if not issubclass(exc_type, self.expected):
            # let unexpected exceptions pass through
            return False
        # store exception, without traceback, for later retrieval
        self.exception = exc_value.with_traceback(None)
        if self.expected_regex is None:
            return True

        expected_regex = self.expected_regex
        if not expected_regex.search(str(exc_value)):
            self._raiseFailure('"{}" does not match "{}"'.format(
                     expected_regex.pattern, str(exc_value)))
        return True
```

I've tried going through [PEP-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to gain some insight, but it's a bit beyond my current knowledge/understanding to make sense of what's contained therein. Could someone explain, in relative layman's terms, the role of `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` in the process of 'catching' the ValueError here and why it is that `__enter__()` is just returning self?

Answer (score 2):

`__enter__()` is for setup, This particular context manager doesn't require any setup. So all it has to do is return object to be specified in the `as` clause, which is just itself.